# get values from master table based on fields in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve the values from master table based on transaction table different col value,

My `master` table will have `username,FirstName,lastName`.

My `transaction` table will have `Id,CreatedUser,UpdatedUser`.

So I want query to get report from sql server ,get FirstName,lastName from master table for createruser and get FirstName,lastName from master table for updateuser.

Ex:
Master Table

```
User ID First Name  Last Name
cer001  Ds  CV
cer002  vb  av
```

Transaction Table

```
id  CreatedUser UdatedUser
2323    cer001  cer002
```

So Report  should get the results like

```
Id  CreatedUser UpdatedUSer
2323    Ds,CV   Vb,av
```

it should be performance wise also good. Please help how to get this

Comment: Please go through ```joins``` in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `self join`

```
select 
      t.Id, m.FirstName +','+m.LastName as  CreatedUser,
      mm.FirstName +','+mm.LastName as  UpdatdUser
from Master m
inner join Transaction  t on t.CreatedUser = m.[User ID]
inner join Master mm on mm.[User ID]= t.UpdatedUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try left join from Transaction table to master table.
LEFT to take care of any NULL values

**[<kbd>see working demo</kbd>](http://rextester.com/CHTZQZ17058)**

Query will be

```
create table [Master] ([User ID] varchar(10), [First Name] varchar(10), [Last Name] varchar(10));
insert into [Master] values
('cer001','Ds','CV'),('cer002','vb','av')


create table [Transaction] (id  int, CreatedUser varchar(10),UpdatedUser varchar(10))
insert into [Transaction] values
(2323, 'cer001','cer002');

select 
ID=T.id,
CreatedUser= ISNULL (M1.[First Name],'')+ ','+ISNULL(M1.[Last Name],'' ),
UpdatedUser= ISNULL (M2.[First Name],'')+ ','+ISNULL(M2.[Last Name],'')

from
[Transaction] T
LEFT JOIN
[Master] M1
   ON T.CreatedUser =M1.[User ID]  
LEFT JOIN
[Master] M2
   ON T.UpdatedUser =M2.[User ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using sub query as below

```
Select
 t.id,
 (Select TOP 1 Rtrim(m.[First Name])+','+RTRIM(m.[Last Name]) from [Master] m where m.[User ID] = t.CreatedUser) as CreatedUser,
  (Select TOP 1 Rtrim(m.[First Name])+','+RTRIM(m.[Last Name]) from [Master] m where m.[User ID] = t.UpdatedUser) as UpdatedUser
from [Transaction] t
```